# How to get actual value from HttpResponse in view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

**Views.py**

```
def process_view(request):
    dspAction = {}
    try:
        google = google(objectId) #google = google(requst, objectId)
        if google['status'] == int(1):
            #some function
    except:
        dspAction['Google Status'] = "Google Action Completed"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dspAction),content_type='application/json')
```

The above function is pretty basic and it's working very well with this `google` function:

```
def google(objectId):
    googelAction = {}
    google['status'] = 1
    return google
```

But for some reason I want `request` in `google` function. If I do this:

```
def google(request, objectId):
    googelAction = {}
    google['status'] = 1
    return HttpResponse(google)
```

and return a HttpResponse object, how can I get the `status` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are saying is you need to return two things (an HttpResponse and the status value) from your `google` function instead of just one thing.

In this case you should return a tuple, eg:

```
def google(request, objectId):
    google = {}
    google['status'] = 1
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(google))  # <-- should be string not dict
    return response, google

def process_view(request):
    dspAction = {}
    try:
        response, google = google(request, objectId)
        if google['status'] == int(1):
            #some function
    except:
        dspAction['Google Status'] = "Google Action Completed"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dspAction),content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

`return HttpResponse(google.status)`

EDIT from comment:
To use the other attributes in the dictionary you need to pass the context variables, usually with render.

```
# view.py
from django.shortcuts import render
... 
return render(request, "template.html", {'google':google})


# template.html
# you can then access the different attributes of the dict
{{ google }} {{ google.status }} {{ google.error }}
```

Comment: Cool that's working but actually `googleAction` is `dict` so in view i will do like `return HttpResponse(google.status, google.error, google.original, etc ...)` like that ?

Comment: I am not using template ./.. I need that value in view itself